# User home directory

Tags: linux, centos, home

I am learning CentOS and I created some users and then deleted, but I used `userdel` without any option.

So will it remove the home directory and other things related to those users? If not then is there any option to remove the remaining contents of those users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual page for [`userdel`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel) describes the `-r` option, which would remove the home-directory at the time you removed the user.  If you did not do it then, you could find files with no known user with the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) option `-nouser`, e.g.,

```
find /home -nouser -delete
```

though you might want to verify the list ***before*** actually deleting the files:

```
find /home -nouser -ls
```

The `-delete` option removes files.  Removing directories would require a different command, e.g.,

```
find /home -type d -nouser -exec rmdir {} \;
```

(although some pathological user may have created a directory with embedded blanks, requiring *more* work).

By the way, `/home` is a *convention*, and you may have created your user's home-directories in other places.